# Lucene Prefix on title/content is extremely slow

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

Here's what I did, and I have only 150 files with 2KB average file size.

```
    BooleanQuery.Builder builder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();

    // filename : prefix search
    BooleanQuery.Builder filenameBuilder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
    for (String s : queryStr.trim().split("\\s+")) {
      PrefixQuery filenameQuery1 = new PrefixQuery(new Term(Indexer.FIELD_NAME_FILENAME, s));
      filenameBuilder.add(filenameQuery1, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
    }

    // content : prefix search
    BooleanQuery.Builder contentBuilder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
    for (String s : queryStr.trim().split("\\s+")) {
      PrefixQuery contentQuery1 = new PrefixQuery(new Term(Indexer.FIELD_NAME_CONTENT, s));
      contentBuilder.add(contentQuery1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    }


    // Set filename and content with different weights.
    Query filenameQuery = filenameBuilder.build();
    Query contentQuery = contentBuilder.build();
    filenameQuery.setBoost(4.0f);
    contentQuery.setBoost(1.0f);

    // Merge filename and content queries : filename OR content
    builder.add(filenameQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
    builder.add(contentQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
    Query query = builder.build();
```

Note :  If I search `filename` only, it seems a lot faster but `filename` + `content` turn out 10+ seconds!

Also, I've tried to change `PrefixQuery` on `content` to `TermQuery` (Which I mean to do exact search), but it still can't make any improvement.

Comment: Can you provide the generated query?

Comment: @alkis Here's `query.toString()` : `((filename:everyday*)^4.0) (+content:everyday*)`, seems the query string is OK to me

Comment: Everything seems fine, but I'm not an expert so... In general is your elastic setup fast? Do you have enough memory etc?